# sencha touch :: how to supress orientation change

Tags: iphone, cordova, sencha-touch, orientation-changes

In my sencha-tpuch / phonegap app on iOS I want my app not to change orientation with the device its used on. how could I suppress orientation change in sencha-touch or what would I override exactly? 
thnx!

Comment: thank you for your answers. but I am really interested if this is possible in sencha tuch, not xcode or phonegap.

Comment: With Sencha it is **NOT** possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to edit any code. All you need to do is go to your configuration files and specify orientations you want to support. By default all 4 orientations are supported, you have to edit it to support orientations you want. Rebuild the application and Go.

The entry should be in **one of the** following files:

phonegap.plist/application.plist/config.xml

Also check [this](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/c2772216a82773e2) link.

With only Sencha Touch, as it cannot force browser not to change orientation, it is **NOT** possible to remove orientation change. See [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?122354-Can-anyone-help-with-disabling-or-removing-the-automatic-Orientation-Change) link.

Answer (score 0):

In your phonegap xcode project find the file `MainViewController.m` in there find the function

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

And return yes for supported orientations.